# Does anyone know where to define the hardware, revision and serial no. fields of /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, customization

I want to ensure my /proc/cpuinfo is accurate.  It currently outputs

```
Hardware        : am335xevm
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

where in the code can I change this to give real values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the version of Linux and processor architecture. Since this is a TI ARM, you can start with: [arch/arm/kernel/setup.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c).

Look for `static int c_show()`.

The *Revision* and *Serial* values are set with [`ATAG_REVISION` and `ATAG_SERIAL`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/setup.h), so an appropriate [**boot loader**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting) can pass them to Linux.  Typically you do not set these in the code but use them as conditionals to handle hardware variations that can not be detected at run time in a machine file or driver.